# WooCommerce: Unable to write certificate file during cURL configuration

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm setting PayPal Express Checkout in WooCommerce. I've set API keys and certificate, but after saving it I got error "Error: Sorry, Easy Setup encountered an error. Please try again.". In log then I see following error:

> 07-08-2016 @ 11:27:22 - WC_Gateway_PPEC_Client::_request: exception is thrown while trying to make a request to PayPal: Unable to write certificate file  during cURL configuration
>
> 07-08-2016 @ 11:27:22 - WC_Gateway_PPEC_Client::_request: returns
>   error: Array (
>       [ACK] => Failure
>       [L_ERRORCODE0] => 2
>       [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Error in WC_Gateway_PPEC_Client::_request
>       [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Unable to write certificate file  during cURL configuration
>       [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error )

Do you have any experience with this error?

Comment: The mode is "Sandbox".

Comment: please add this code in your config file if your website has SSL certificate      define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj My website does not have SSL certificate. Anyway - what is the origin of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to change settings of the server and force HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

well you have  configure your curl setting check out this  http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/ 
i think it will may help you working fine in my case

Comment: This does not seem like Wordpress-related solution. My website does not have SSL certificate as well.